# Making a div hidden on page load and then unhidden when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried a technique that I read about somewhere, but it isn't working. The technique was to make a class called `hidden` that is removed on a function call. Since I'm new to using JQuery, I think something might be wrong with how I was writing the onclick function. I'll post my attempt and then I'll appreciate it if you can help me correct my error(s).

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="function() {$('newthreaddiv').removeClass('hidden');}">New Thread</button>
    <div class="boardbox hidden" id="newthreaddiv">
        <p>Username:<input class="threadipt" type="text"</p>
        <p>Password:<input class="threadipt" type="text"></p>
        <p>Title:<input class="threadipt" type="text"></p>
        <p>Content:</p>
        <button class="threadbutton">bold</button>
        <button class="threadbutton">italicize</button>
        <button class="threadbutton">underline</button>
        <button class="threadbutton">insert image</button>
        <textarea id="newthreadtxt"></textarea>
        <p><button onlick="phpfunction">Create Thread</button></p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.boardbox
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
}

div.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you do not use inline javascript. Instead, create a listener for click events on the button.

```
<button id="new_thread">New Thread</button>
<div class="boardbox hidden" id="newthreaddiv">
   ...
</div>
```

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('#new_thread').on('click',function() {
        jQuery('#newthreaddiv').show();
    });

});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xr36Z/2/)

---

**METHOD 2**

However, if you need the javascript to be inline, don't use a function:

```
<button onclick="$('#newthreaddiv').removeClass('hidden');">New Thread</button>
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xr36Z/3/)

---

**METHOD 3**

You can use a function, but it will need to be an "[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)" (and I don't see any purpose in this context):

```
<button onclick="(function() {$('#newthreaddiv').removeClass('hidden');}())">New Thread</button>
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zfaB6/)

Comment: +1 You put in way more effort than I did. OP, if you read this, accept this post as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

`function() {$('newthreaddiv')` should be `function() {$('#newthreaddiv')` You are missing the `#`.

Also, I'm not sure if this is just a typo or in your actual code, but you are missing a closing bracket (`>`) on your username input field.